# Postgres - double quote around schema name cause 42P01:relation "schemana.tablename" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, double-quotes

Version is PostgreSQL 13.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-10), 64-bit

By default, Postgres query accepts double quote around both schema and table names, e.g. *select * from “ads”.”MyTableName”*.  In our setup, it throws **42P01 error relation “ads.MyTableName” does not exist**. If no double quote around schema name, e.g. *select * from ads.”MyTableName”*, the query runs fine.

Is there settings in Postgres db server or db level that changes it?

Comment: Works here. 1) Are you sure whatever client you are using is not doing `"ads.MyTableName"`? 2) Not sure if this is a copy and paste thing but the quotes look like typographical quotes, not straight quotes.

Comment: “ads.MyTableName” Is very different from ads.”MyTableName”. Check your input